# Не удалось загрузить тип "System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2"

Tags: c#, json

При открытии программы на любом другом компьютере появляется ошибка:

> ERROR: Не удалось загрузить тип "System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2" из сборки "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".

На своем, на котором писала, всё нормально работает.
Использую *newtonjson.dll*. Ошибка как раз возникает, когда код обращается к ней.

Comment: Имеет смысл на этом "любом другом компьютере" обновить .NET Framework.

Comment: Regent, спасибо! Обновление помогло

Comment: @Regent, я хочу поставить ваш комментарий, как ответ, но у меня не отображается серая галка, ни в браузере, ни в приложении, не подскажете в чем причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для устранения ошибки необходимо [обновить .NET Framework](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48130) (как минимум до 4.5) на "любом другом компьютере".